# Dplyr R - multiple conditionals when using distinct() or something entirely different?

Tags: r, conditional-statements, distinct

Let me just say that I'm not totally attached to the use of `distinct()` for my problem, I'm open to all suggestions for tackling it. Here's the puzzle pieces:

```
Date <- c(1,1,2,2)
Group <- c("A","A","B","B")
Result <- c("Aa","Ab","Aa","SB")
df <- cbind(Date, Group, Result)
df
     Date Group Result
[1,] "1"  "A"   "Aa"  
[2,] "1"  "A"   "Ab"  
[3,] "2"  "B"   "Aa"  
[4,] "2"  "B"   "SB"
```

The results I'm aiming for are distinct `Date`, such that either one of the rows containing Aa or Ab are chosen (subsetted), and any row containing SB is chosen over Aa or Ab or Ac or ... . I'm having a lot of trouble doing this in an efficient way for a large data frame. I don't have a quality attempt to show here.

In reality, `Group` A and B have many more time based observations, there are also many more different groups. When data are uploaded twice (or more) on the same `Date` for one particular `Group` there should really only be one `Date` entry with the more important `Result`.

UPDATED:

Expected subset of the output from above, after filtering and such:

```
     Date Group Result
[1,] "1"  "A"   "Aa"    
[2,] "2"  "B"   "SB"
```

OR

```
     Date Group Result
[1,] "1"  "A"   "Ab"    
[2,] "2"  "B"   "SB"
```

Comment: Can you update your post with expected output

Comment: Updated with expected output!

Comment: Do you want the first result or the second, or both?

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`, but not `distinct`:

```
library(dplyr)

Date <- c(1,1,2,2)
Group <- c("A","A","B","B")
Result <- c("Aa","Ab","Aa","SB")
# Use data.frame, not cbind, as this produced a matrix
df <- data.frame(Date, Group, Result)

# To get your first answer
summarise(group_by(df, Date, Group), 
                   Result = first(Result))

# To get your second answer
summarise(group_by(df, Date, Group), 
                   Result = last(Result))

# To combine all the options
summarise(group_by(df, Date, Group), 
                   Result = paste(Result, collapse = ", "))
```

Answer (score 0):

The unique Results need to be ranked in order of importance.  That could be done either manually or using some sort of algorithm.  Both methods are shown below.  The ranked Results are then used to find the highest ranked Result for each Date Group combination.  Code could look like:

```
  library(dplyr)
  df <- data.frame(df)
#
# manually list unique Results in order of increasing importance
#
  Result_rank <- c("Aa","Ab","SB")
#
# Or use an algorithm to rank unique Results in order of importance;
# For the example, the algorithm might be:
#
  Result_rank <- c(grep("^A",unique(df$Result), value=TRUE), 
                   grep("SB",unique(df$Result), value=TRUE))
#
# summarize by highest ranked Result for each Date and Group
#
  df_important <- df %>% group_by( Date, Group) %>%
                  summarize(Result= Result_rank[max(match(Result, Result_rank))])
```

which gives the result

```
   Date  Group Result
  <fctr> <fctr>  <chr>
1      1      A     Ab
2      2      B     SB
```